# Remove text within certain identifiers from html string in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, htmltext

For a project, I'm trying import htmlText into flash, and then remove any items flash will not process. For example, the html I want to import contains custom "[caption][/caption]" code. I essentially want to remove these identifiers and any text from in between them so that flash will not display them in a text field. Does anyone have a good suggestion/example for me? I have been trying to figure out how to use regular expressions to do this, but have been unsuccessful in finding a good guide for it and so have failed.

And example of text I'm trying to filter:

```
<em>Pushmo</em> is a game filled with questions. How do I solve this puzzle? Is that a 8-bit Mario's face? Why is this old, obese blob making tons of death traps that easily ensnare and encase unsuspecting children?

[caption id="attachment_37414" align="alignleft" width="400" caption="The fat, red sumo goes into the most dangous place imaginable."]<a href="/2011/12/pushmo-review/pushmo-3ds-title-screen/" rel="attachment wp-att-37414"><img class="size-medium wp-image-37414" title="Pushmo-title" src="/2011/12/pushmo-3ds-title-screen-400x203.jpg" alt="Pushmo Title Screen" width="400" height="203" /></a>[/caption]

<em>Pushmo</em> is a downloadable puzzle game in the 3DS eShop. In <em>Pushmo</em> you take on the role of Mallo, an amorphic red sumo wrestler with the mind of an Einstienian savant.
```

I'm looking to be able to detect identifying text and remove anything between them. I'd appreciate any suggestions anyone can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` to achieve this without regex.

Also you should have a look at `String.replace`

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html

and an as3 regex tutorial:

http://snipplr.com/view/6608/as3-regular-expression-basics/

finally a tutorial for pure regex:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: I'd like to use string replace, but the values between the identifiers will not be the same. I could possibly use index of and run a loop somehow. Reg expressions seem like they should make sense, but I haven't been able to get a custom one to work, so I think that'll require a lot more study if I'm going to do it that way. Every time I try a regex it's not finding the proper term. I don't think I understand the key to it.

Comment: Regex is hard to understand at the beginning, but if you stick with it you can start to make sense of it. I'm no expert at it myself but I do know that if you get the indexes of '[caption]' and '[/caption]' and get the substrings around those indexes you can delete whats in between

Comment: Awesome, I just tried that and got it to work! All I need to do now is put it in a loop until the index hits -1 so that it will remove all instances. Thanks man! (or woman)

Comment: except, doh.. turns out i can't delete everything in between those brackets. I need to preserve the call to the image. now I need to figure out how to separate that out.